# How to call a method in Managed beans when I click in thymeleaf button

Tags: ejb, thymeleaf, managed-bean

I want to know if it is possible to call a method present in my managed beans when I click in a button(the button is created with Thymeleaf).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I do't know if there is an option to do it directly, I don't think so. But the solution could be easier: why not your button submits to a endpoint which executes this method?

```
<button onclick="execute()">Click me</button>

<script>
    function execute() {
        //$.get() or
        $.post( "/the/endpoint", function(data) {
             $('#test').html(data);
        });
    }
</script>
```

Then `/the/endpoint`is your `@Request`method which internally executes the method you want:

```
@Controller
public class YourController {

    @GET
    @Path("/the/endpoint")
    public Response executeMethod() {
        yourMethod(); //Executes your method
        return Response.status(200);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but I don't want to use Javascript.